# Rewrite variable url in .htaccess from page.{variable}.php to /page/{variable}

Tags: php, .htaccess

I don't have much experience with .htaccess file, but I want to achieve the following:

`/page/{variable}` should be redirected to the file `page.{variable}.php`

I tried something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/$ page.$.php`
```

But that didn't work. How can I rewrite this?

Comment: Won't `page.something.php` cause a 404 unless you have some other rule to strip `.something` off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the matching expression, [`$`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html) signifies the end of the string.
What you want is a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) which you can refer to using `$1` (for the *first* captured group):

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.+) page.$1.php
```